# How is "They are flying planes" ambiguous?

Tags: syntax

I need to explain how the sentence *They are flying planes* is ambiguous. I understand that one possible meaning could be "they are controlling planes" but I'm not sure about other possible meanings. Could this sentence mean "these are flying planes" as in the response to the question *What are those?*

Comment: 'They are flying planes' could mean 'they are planes which are flying right now', or 'they are planes which are capable of flying'.

Comment: The sentence could also refer to people who are a sports field flying model aeroplanes.

Comment: @RonaldSole or even real pilots flying real planes. "Pilots are flying planes"

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is ambiguous in many, many, ways.

For example, it could mean:

1. They are at this moment flying planes.
2. They are flying planes from time to time
3. The planes are able to fly
4. The planes are in the air at the moment

Generally speaking, the context in which the sentence is found will eliminate the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

The expected answer is that "flying" could be part of a present continuous construction, and it means that "they (people) are pilots of planes".  Or it could be an adjective/participle modifier of planes.  They (=the planes) are "flying planes", and not the other type of plane.

The first interpretation has the same structure as "They are playing tennis."
The second interpretation has the same structure as "They are big cats."

The second interpretation is odd; I can't think many situations in which we would need to clarify that aeroplanes are capable of flight, that would be assumed.  Nor would you need to distinguish between aeroplanes and geometric planes.  So the assumed sense, without any other context is the first interpretation.

And, of course, in real-life, context would remove any doubt. There might also be a slight difference in the stress (but probably not enough to be certain.)

That is the grammatical ambiguity, of course there are lots of other ambiguities.  We don't know what, or who "they" refers to.  We don't know the colour of the planes, or how long they have been flying etc. etc.  But this kind of semantic ambiguity is probably not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

There is another grammatical interpretation of "They are flying planes." Where "flying" is a gerund and "planes" is a verb. Best understood by comparison with "The facts are smoking kills." Someone has asked "What are the facts about flying?"

Comment: This adds nothong to the existing answers.

Comment: I know several people who study linguistics who disagree.

Comment: I'm voting to delete because this interpretation seems to be invalid. M-W lists two definitions for the intransitive verb "to plane": "to work with a plane" and "to do the work of a plane" (where I think it is clear that the tool is meant, not the vehicle). I don't undersstand how "flying" can perform either of those actions.